# why cannot push back address of element in vector<bool> to vector<bool*>?

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, boolean

```
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

bool myfunc(bool* i,bool* j){
    return *i<*j;
}

int main(){
    vector<bool> a;
    a.push_back(true);
    a.push_back(false);
    a.push_back(false);
    a.push_back(true);
    a.push_back(true);

    vector<bool*> aa;
    for(int i=0;i<a.size();i++){
        aa.push_back(&a[i]);
    }

    sort(aa.begin(),aa.end(),myfunc);
    for(int i=0;i<aa.size();i++){
        printf("%d\n",*(aa[i]));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

but it cannot compile and say:

```
no viable conversion from '__bit_iterator<std::__1::vector<bool, std::__1::allocator<bool> >, false>' to 'const value_type' (aka 'bool *const')
    aa.push_back(&a[i]);
```

but I cannot believe it has wrong logic code because I remember I can do some similar works with int, so I tried convert some bool to integer:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int myfunc(int* i,int* j){
    return *i<*j;
}

int main(){
    vector<int> a;
    a.push_back(true);
    a.push_back(false);
    a.push_back(false);
    a.push_back(true);
    a.push_back(true);

    vector<int*> aa;
    for(int i=0;i<a.size();i++){
        aa.push_back(&a[i]);
    }

    sort(aa.begin(),aa.end(),myfunc);
    for(int i=0;i<aa.size();i++){
        printf("%d\n",*(aa[i]));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

but this time it can compile and run:

```
0
0
1
1
1
```

why?

Comment: `&a[i]` gives the error "cannot take the address of a temporary". I'm not sure why your compiler didn't give that error.

Comment: @0x499602D2: That error message looks like it corresponds to `push_back(a[i])` (without the `&`)

Comment: @BenVoigt `vector<bool>::operator[]` returns a prvalue of class type. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9302a6ba73fcef6c

Comment: @0x499602D2 I meant the error message in the question

Comment: @BenVoigt Right, he probably removed the `&` and copy-pasted the old code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because [vector<bool>](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool) is special and may pack bits more tightly than a regular array of booleans. As a result, you cannot get a normal pointer or reference to the booleans inside it.

Comment: Of course, he could use `vector<bool>::iterator` instead of `bool*`